# I could not able to test API level below 17 in android using appium

Tags: android, eclipse, automation, junit4, appium

I need to know whether via appium API level below 17 is possible for Android?

For many sites and appium group I found that in capability "device" instead of "android" if we use "selendroid" we can run the testscripts for API level below 17.

But when I tried that, I could not able to test API level below 17 in android using appium when I give capabilities device:Android its works fine for API level above 17, but when we give device:selendroid error occurs. The error which given at last.

Can anyone help me to run the test where API level below 17 in android using appium?

I am using Updated appium server v1.0.0-beta.2 (i.e, appium@0.18.2), tested using real device Android version 4.1.2, using mac machine.

```
info: [ADB] 1 device(s) connected

info: Setting device id to 14c62c71

info: [ADB] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)

debug: executing: /Users/gowtham.r/sdk/platform-tools//adb -s 14c62c71 wait-for-device

debug: executing: /Users/gowtham.r/sdk/platform-tools//adb -s 14c62c71 shell "echo 'ready'"

info: Starting logcat capture

info: Rebuilt selendroid apk does not exist, uninstalling any instances of it on device to make way for new one

info: Uninstalling com.dext.shoply.selendroid

debug: executing: /Users/gowtham.r/sdk/platform-tools//adb -s 14c62c71 shell "am force-stop com.dext.shoply.selendroid"

debug: executing: /Users/gowtham.r/sdk/platform-tools//adb -s 14c62c71 uninstall com.dext.shoply.selendroid

debug: App was not uninstalled, maybe it wasn't on device?

info: Rebuilt selendroid server does not exist, inserting modified manifest

info: Inserting selendroid manifest

info: Checking whether aapt is present

info: Cleaning up appium session

error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Could not find aapt; do you have the Android SDK installed and the tools + platform-tools folders added to your PATH?
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is for something not installed on your system. You should look into why you dont have "aapt" installed and go from there. Might need to open up the android sdk installer and download something else